# My PC blocks the mouse and keyboard after power on, is it a virus or what?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, mouse, virus

My PC after power on blocks the mouse and keyboard, is it a virus or what?
After few second windows freeze and all the keyboard and mouse movement do not works.

I have Windows XP SP3.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Do they start to work again eventually? Are they usb or PS/2? Can you use the keyboard in the BIOS?

Comment: USB devices i guess?

Comment: can you get into safe mode?

Comment: @Kyle
no the do not work again.
they are PS/2
yes in the BIOS I can

@Aki
No they are PS/2

@madmaze
no I can't get into safe mode

Comment: Hmm very odd I have never encountered a PS/2 keyboard that had this problem... maybe something is wrong with keyboard?

Comment: No becouse since today alle works well.
Before the keyboard and mouse blocks I can use those for 2 or 3 minutes on the Windows XP.
Which tests I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: I have never ran into a problem such as this before. If I was in you shoes I would start by trying to narrow it down. Use a linux live boot cd, based entirely on suspicion I think it might be the OS. If it works in Linux and the BIOS it is pretty safe to say the OS is the problem here.

Comment: I've run a linux live cd and the keyboard and mouse works well. Now what you suggest to me to do with the Windows XP OS?

Comment: Try a repair of the install. Have you installed or added hardware since this started happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may well have solved it already, but a possible cause of your freezing and a solution are outlined [here](http://forums.techsoup.org/cs/community/f/23/p/18720/74434.aspx#74434). (If you have XP Pro, that is - you didn't specify.) Worked for me.

(Sorry, I'd link to the but the relevant part is half way down the page. Furthermore, being a newb I can only use one link per post.)

If it's not that then I can't be very helpful; all I can suggest is to run `chkdsk` or try a system restore.